# How map through multiple arrays and conditional render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I am working on a react blog type application and I'm currently having issues trying to figure out the best approach to solve my problem. Right now i have a postbody component that sends props from redux to a postbody template component with the data it retrieves from redux. Right now it maps through a const called postItems. I have a function that returns comments with the same post Id used. What i need to accomplish is once it maps through the post body template, if there are comments with the same post Ids for it to display those in the same postBodyTemplate component.

For my PostBody Component I  have:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PostBodyTemplate from './postBodyTemplate';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions';
import { fetchComments } from '../actions/commentActions';
import axios from 'axios';

class PostBody extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchPosts();
    // this.props.fetchComments();
}

render() {




 const reversedProps = this.props.posts.reverse();

var activeComments = [];
const getComments = async (id) => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://10.6.254.22:5000/comments/" +id);
  if (response.data.length > 0) {
    console.log(response.data);
    activeComments.push(response.data)
    return response.data
    //  activeComments = response.data;
  }
};

const postIdMap = post => post.id;
const postIds = reversedProps.map(postIdMap);
console.log(postIds);
// console.log(commentIds);

postIds.map(getComments);


  const postItems = reversedProps.map(post => (

      <PostBodyTemplate key={post.id} title={post.title} postBody={post.postBody} giphyUrl = {post.giphyUrl} userWhoPosted={post.userIdName}/>

  ));



  return (
      <div>
         <h1>{postItems}</h1>
      </div>
  )
}
}

PostBody.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  fetchComments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  posts: state.posts.items,
  // comments: state.comments.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts, fetchComments })(PostBody);
```

When I do postIds.map(getComments) it iterates through the post ID and checks the comments api endpoint and retrieves post with those post Ids. It returns the data as such:

```
Array(1)0: {id: 1, postId: 86, commentBody: "This is a test comment", giphyUrl: "https://media2.giphy.com/", postPicture: "pic.com", …}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
postBody.js:41 
Array(1)
0: {id: 2, postId: 85, commentBody: "Another Comment", giphyUrl: "https://meida.com", postPicture: "pic.com", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want these posts that are retrieved to be also included inside the post body template component. This is the post body template and have also added the comment component inside it. I dont know if this is the best practice either.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import EcoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Eco';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Comment from './comments';



const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
  },
}));

const fr = {
  float: 'right'
}

const giphyRes = {
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px'
}



     export default function PostBodyTemplate(props) {

         const classes = useStyles();
        //  render() {
             return (
                <Grid item xs={12} xl={8} lg={8} style={fr}>
                <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardContent>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" style={fr}>
                      {props.userWhoPosted} Gave A VH5 To Julio
                  </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                      {props.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                      {props.postBody}
                    </Typography>
                    <img src={props.giphyUrl} style={giphyRes}/>
                </Paper>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                    <FavoriteIcon />
                    <div>Add Gif</div>
                  </IconButton>
                  <IconButton aria-label="share">
                    <EcoIcon />
                    <div>Add Photo</div>
                  </IconButton>
                <TextField
                  id="standard-full-width"
                  label="Reply"
                  style={{ margin: 8 }}
                  placeholder="Reply to Author"
                  fullWidth
                  margin="normal"
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />
                  <Button size="small">Submit</Button>
                </CardActions>

                <Comment {**THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE COMMENTS TO GO IF POST HAS COMMENTS**} />

              </Card>
              </Grid>
             )
        //  }
     }
```

What I would like to accomplish is something of this nature but am having trouble:

```
const postItems = reversedProps.map(post => (

  <PostBodyTemplate key={post.id} title={post.title} postBody={post.postBody} giphyUrl = 

{post.giphyUrl} userWhoPosted={post.userIdName}/>

 **If the result of PostIds.Map(getComments) returns a post ID that equals the same Post Id as 
 above, send that information to the comments component and have it populate the comments for this 
 post specifically ** So after it populates the post body i want it to basically map through 
  reversedProps.map(getComments) after and display the comments by passing 


  ));
```

Below is comments component if it helps.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/postActions';
import { fetchComments } from '../actions/commentActions';
import axios from 'axios';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';



const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
  },
}));

const fr = {
  float: 'right'
}

const giphyRes = {
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px'
}


export default function Comment() {

  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <div>                 
          <Paper className={classes.root} value={comment.postId}>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
            {comment.commentBody}
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="p">
              {comment.userIdName} replied to the post. 
            </Typography>
        </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}


// export default Comment;
```

This is alot to read through so i greatly appreciate it in advanced.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are fetching the posts from a REST service and storing them in Redux, and then fetching comments for each post with another REST call as you render the posts. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes the post are getting called from my post Api that gets sent to the redux state, the comments are getting pulled from comments api and just getting used there not sent to redux. I am trying to get it to map through the post first and post all of them, and check if those post have comments by checking to see if the comments have the post id, and if they do i want to send it to the comments component to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that to conditionally render data in react, it is best to use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
<YourComponent <h1>{isPostAvailable ? 'yes' : 'no'}</h1> />
```

In the above code, if post is available, yes is printed other wise you get no.

Answer (score 0):

REST calls are asynchronous in React/Redux, so you should always store the results in Redux to keep the UI responsive. You need to decide when to trigger the call for the comments: It could be done when the posts are received, or when you are sure you will display a post, but in either case you will want to put the result into Redux. You can create an object where the postID is the key, and the Array of comments is the value. Then you will render the comments from Redux by mapping Redux state to React props, and pass the Array (if any) to the Comments component. As the comments arrive, the change in state will trigger re-rendering and fill them in.

You will want to avoid triggering the Comments call from the rendering code directly because that may (probably) end up sending duplicate calls since any change in state can cause a re-render. When you send the call to load the posts, add a "PostsLoading"=true and PostsLoaded=false flags to your redux state. In the reducer, set PostsLoading to false and PostsLoaded to true. You can check these in your componentWillReceiveProps method and use the change in those flags to decide when to call the comments service.